# Saltstack multidot custom function

Tags: salt-stack

I'm writing custom states for saltstack for my current project and feeling quite comfortable with `%company%.%action-domain%.%action-name%` naming scheme (e.g. `foo.infrastructure.running`). However, i can't get it running - i receive errors like `state foo.infrastructure not found` for `foo.infrastructure.running` state apply even if i define `__virtual__` function in module. Is it possible to use naming scheme other than `%file%.%function%` for states?

Comment: could you update your question with a code sample ?

Answer (score 0):

Salt's execution modules and state modules are formed like `cmd.run` and `pkg.installed` because they map to the python module.python function

Comment: To be honest, i was asking because i wanted to have more than one level depth of modules, because, in turn, i felt very uncomfortably storing everything in one file. Correct be if i'm wrong, but there is not much difference between accessing module `foo` and `foo.bar` except for directory traversal.